# Eager tf.GradientTape() returns only Nones

Tags: tensorflow

I try to calculate the gradients with Tensorflow in the eager mode, but
tf.GradientTape () returns only None values. I can not understand why.
The gradients are calculated in the update_policy () function.

The output of the line:

```py
grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
```

is

```py
{list}<class 'list'>:[None, None, ... ,None]
```

Here is the code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session

import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()
print(tf.executing_eagerly())

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)


class PGEagerAtariNetwork:
    def __init__(self, state_space, action_space, lr, gamma):
        self.state_space = state_space
        self.action_space = action_space
        self.gamma = gamma

        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        # Conv
        self.model.add(
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=[8, 8], strides=[4, 4], activation='relu',
                                   input_shape=(84, 84, 4,),
                                   name='conv1'))
        self.model.add(
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=[4, 4], strides=[2, 2], activation='relu', name='conv2'))
        self.model.add(
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=[4, 4], strides=[2, 2], activation='relu', name='conv3'))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='flatten'))

        # Fully connected
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4, name='dr1'))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3, name='dr2'))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu', name='fc3'))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1, name='dr3'))

        # Logits
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=self.action_space, activation=None, name='logits'))

        self.model.summary()

        # Optimizer
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)

    def get_probs(self, s):
        s = s[np.newaxis, :]
        logits = self.model.predict(s)
        probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits).numpy()
        return probs

    def update_policy(self, s, r, a):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = self.model.predict(s)
            policy_loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=a, logits=logits)
            policy_loss = policy_loss * tf.stop_gradient(r)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(policy_loss)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: `predict()` returns `numpy` type. It should be tensor. This is the first problem. Remove `.numpy()` in `predict()`.

Comment: The `update_policy ()` function does not call the `predict ()` function. This is independent to calculate the gradients.
The `update_policy ()` function calls `self.model.predict ()`. I change the function to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak German.

Comment: Sorry that was my translater

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure that the variables are being watched? Try adding `tape.watch(self.model.trainable_variables)` before calling `self.model.predict()` in `update_policy()`

Comment: Same problem with `tape.watch(self.model.trainable_variables)`

Comment: You don't have a forward pass. That is the problem.

Comment: add `print(tape.watched_variables())` wight before grads line. The output is  () ?

Comment: I thought the forward pass ist when I call `logits = self.model.predict(s)`. When I call `print(tape.watched_variables())` the output is `()`

Comment: Sorry, when I call print(tape.watched_variables()) the output is a big list with weights

Comment: Try substituting `logits = self.model.predict(s)` with `logits = self.model(s)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have a forward pass in your model. The `Model.predict()` method returns `numpy()` array without taping the forward pass. Take a look at this example:

Given a following data and model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones((1, 2), np.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1]])

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(2, ))])
```

First we use `predict()`:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model.predict(x_train)
    print('`logits` has type {0}'.format(type(logits)))
    # `logits` has type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_train, logits=logits)
    reduced = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    grads = tape.gradient(reduced, model.trainable_variables)
    print('grads are: {0}'.format(grads))
    # grads are: [None, None]
```

Now we use model's input:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(x_train)
    print('`logits` has type {0}'.format(type(logits)))
    # `logits` has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
    xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_train, logits=logits)
    reduced = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    grads = tape.gradient(reduced, model.trainable_variables)
    print('grads are: {0}'.format(grads))
    # grads are: [<tf.Tensor: id=2044, shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
    # array([[ 0.77717704, -0.777177  ],
    #        [ 0.77717704, -0.777177  ]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: id=2042, 
    # shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 0.77717704, -0.777177  ], dtype=float32)>]
```

So use model's `__call__()` (i.e. `model(x)`) for forward pass and not `predict()`.

Comment: We wrote the same in less than 30 sec difference). This should work, although I'd say that it simply because `.predict` returns numpy array, which cannot be differentiated by TF.  `__call__` returns tensor

Comment: @Sharky, Sorry about that ;-) + You are right that numpy cannot be differentiated, but it also doesn't tape the forward pass, otherwise calls to `predict()` would eventually overflow the buffer.

Comment: @Sharky, Thanks, I owe you one too now.

Comment: @Sharky you are right upvote is more than deserved. For me this is not possible I need at least 15 reputation before I can vote.

Comment: Now you do. Question is also worth it.